# Hibernate setParameter String

Tags: hibernate

return em.createQuery("""
                select s.description, avg(c.taktTime)
                from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, FwmsUserEntity u, SkillTypeEntity t
                where c.fwmsUser = u.id
                   **AND s.description IN (:skillsList)**

```
            ).setParameter("skillsList", skillsListStr).getResultList()
```

does not return any values. List size 0 and there were no SQL errors.

But if I do

return em.createQuery("""
                select s.description, avg(c.taktTime)
                from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, FwmsUserEntity u, SkillTypeEntity t
                where c.fwmsUser = u.id
                   **AND s.description in ('Shelf Count', 'Notion Count', 'Tube Count', '2nd Count')**

```
            ).setParameter("skillsList", skillsListStr).getResultList()
```

it works fine.

my String skillsListStr =  "Shelf Count, Notion Count, Tube Count, 2nd Count";

How can I use the setParameter to set "skillsListStr"?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you declared your "skillsListStr" variable as a String, but it should be a List instead, because that is what is specified as the parameter.

Try something like this:

`List<String> skillsListStr = Arrays.toList(new String[]{"Shelf Count", "Notion Count", "Tube Count", "2nd Count"});`